# With the Browserify API, use require and exclude on a local file

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, browserify

With the Browserify API and Gulp, I have this:

```
var browserify = require('browserify');
var gulp = require('gulp');
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');

var dependencies = [
  'lodash',
  './test.js',
];

gulp.task('lib', function() {
  return browserify()
    .require(dependencies)
    .bundle()
    .pipe(source('lib.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
});

gulp.task('app', function() {
  return browserify('./app.js')
    .external(dependencies)
    .bundle()
    .pipe(source('bundle.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
});
```

And in `app.js` I have this:

```
var _ = require('lodash');
var test = require('./test.js');
```

The Lodash line works fine, but the `./test.js` does not work. I get the error `Error: Cannot find module '/test.js'`.

How do I get this to work?

For some reason, the key differs between `bundle.js` and `lib.js`. In `lib.js`, the key for `test.js` is the full path (`/Users/gary/Projects/browserify-test/test.js`) whereas in `bundle.js` it's looking for a module with the key `./test.js`. If I manually change the latter to be the same as the former, then it works.

I'm guessing that ultimately, Browserify doesn't support `require` on local files that are excluded from the same bundle.

Comment: I assume that you have exported your code in test.js?

Comment: Yes, I have exported it. It's a proper module. It will work if the two bundles are in a single file.

Comment: try  the path option: return browserify({paths: ['./node_modules','./src/js/']}), then require('test.js'); should work

Comment: I'm not sure what that would accomplish. All my code is in `./` just to make testing simple. So `paths: ['./']` would simply require that I type `require('test.js');` rather than `require('./test.js');`, but would be unlikely to fix the underlying problem, wouldn't it?

Comment: Indeed I just tried it, and I have the same problem.

Comment: I was able to narrow down the problem. See my new text at the bottom of my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

browserify needs an absolute path to retrieve the file and it leaves that as the bundle key.  The way to fix it is to use the `expose` option...

In your build..

```
var dependencies = [
  'lodash',
  {file: './test.js', expose: 'test'},
];
```

and in app.js...

```
var _ = require('lodash');
var test = require('test');
```